# (Why) would I use both an .editorconfig file and the Visual Studio Code workspace settings in a project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editorconfig

Assuming I am only using Visual Studio Code as the editor, is there an advantage to include a *.editorconfig* file in a project if I already have workspace settings saved?

Or, a disadvantage: such as *.editorconfig* potentially overwrite my Visual Studio Code settings or vice versa?

Answer (score 9):

#### TL;DR;

Basically, *.editorconfig* has advantages when:

- you're working in a team

or

- a way to preserve your settings, so you can easily use them in other projects in case you lose your existing IDE settings (e.g., customise stuff in your IDE but then format your computer)

#### More information

The `.editorconfig` file is usually committed into the code repository, so it can be used by multiple people working on the same repository. This enables you to have code *consistency* across all team members. You might like using *tabs*, but the rules are set to use *spaces*. Sorry, team rules override your personal rules. Consistency wins.

Visual Studio Code workspace settings (or any built-in IDE workspace settings) can be *individually* configured (per person) and thus could be different and make the files in the repository, inconsistent. You might use *tabs* while other people use *spaces* and it messes things up for *everyone*, because now you're all fighting on coding style(s).

`.editorconfig` files might require a third-party extension to work with your IDE (which is the case with Visual Studio Code) while IDE workspace settings are baked in to the IDE (no extra download(s) required). *Note*: Visual Studio (as opposed to Visual Studio Code) has this baked in.

IDEs usually allow you to 'back up' your IDE settings ... so it's true you can back up your settings and use them later on.

Not everyone in a team always uses the same IDEs. Again, means nothing if you're just working solo on something.

Answer (score 2):

First off, *.editorconfig* only works in Visual Studio Code using [a plugin](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode). The advantage for *.editorconfig* is that other editors also recognize it. The advantage for Visual Studio Code workspace settings is that it doesn't require a plugin and can include more settings.

From what I can tell, *.editorconfig* takes precedence over user and workspace settings. Although I couldn't find an official statement on this (but also one hint is that [they mention](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode#known-issues) this not being true for one of the settings as a bug).

I would use *.editorconfig* for what I can and include the Visual Studio Code workspace configuration for the remaining settings. I'd avoid conflicting settings.

Comment: One use of .editorconfig files is if you work in teams (and commit the .editorconfig file), since it overrides user/workspace settings you can enforce its supported settings across the team easily.